# How I can implement zoom in Fresco Library?

Tags: android, zooming, pinch, fresco

I'm using Fresco to visualize images from the assets folder in a view. My problem is that by default the class `com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView` doesn't have a zoom/pinch method. Is there any property or something in the XML to enable this, or which is the way to achieve it?

Answer (score 8):

this is Fresco ZoomableDraweeView

[ZoomableDraweeView](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/zoomable/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/zoomable/ZoomableDraweeView.java)

To see how to use please take a look at this:

[ZoomableDraweeView-sample](https://github.com/kunny/ZoomableDraweeView-sample)

Hope it help you!

Comment: I've read it.But the effect of zoom is not good.When zoom out, the viewpager can't scroll.And it seems to be not supporting gif.

Answer (score 3):

[PhotoDraweeView](https://github.com/ongakuer/PhotoDraweeView) enables double tap and pinch zoom (similar to the [PhotoView](https://github.com/chrisbanes/PhotoView) library) to the [Fresco](https://github.com/facebook/fresco) library.

Add the photodraweeview dependency in the app gradle:

```
dependencies {
implementation 'com.facebook.fresco:fresco:1.9.0'
implementation 'me.relex:photodraweeview:1.1.3'
}
```

replace the XML code:

```
<com.facebook.drawee.view.SimpleDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    fresco:placeholderImage="@drawable/my_drawable"/>
```

with

```
<me.relex.photodraweeview.PhotoDraweeView
    android:id="@+id/my_image_view"
    android:layout_width="130dp"
    android:layout_height="130dp"
    app:placeholderImage="@drawable/my_drawable"/>
```

In the java code `onCreate()` set the url:

```
PhotoDraweeView mPhotoDraweeView = findViewById(R.id.my_image_view);
mPhotoDraweeView.setPhotoUri(Uri.parse("http://your.image.url"));
```

Comment: And it doesn't work and if you press to many times on the picture with multipile fingers the application will crash.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [ZoomableDraweeView](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/zoomable/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/zoomable/ZoomableDraweeView.java) for pinch-to-zoom feature

Answer (score 1):

The fresco's [ZoomableDraweeView](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/samples/zoomable/src/main/java/com/facebook/samples/zoomable/ZoomableDraweeView.java) sample added some new features such as double-tap to zoom and enable scrolling in ViewPager when the `ZoomableDraweeView` zooms in. I've wrote a demo for this sample in which I've also optimized some default behaviors to make it more perfect.

Please refer to: https://github.com/ibosong/CommentGallery

Comment: The best library for zoom. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The other answers do not have double tap to zoom functionality. I've built a library that works for double tap to zoom and pinch to zoom
[Fresco Zoom](https://github.com/arlindiDev/FrescoDoubleTapZoom)